# Accessing methods or classes from another java file/class from Activity

Tags: java, android

I am new to android studio but I am getting better at it as I program more and more. I have a MainActivity.java and the .xml file. And a friend provided me some code that it suppose to work with the input areas. The problem is I do not know how to access that regular java file. So that I can use it the way it is intended. He was using eclipse to build everything while I use android studio. I have the buttons all good to go and areas of input good to go but I just dont know how to implement his code. Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

See examples to understand what I am trying to do.

"In android studio" a class is created called WaterDetails.java with a .xml file called activity_water_details.xml. There are calculations that were  made for the duration that I need to be able to use or access from a java file created in eclipse called DurationCalculations.java. I have tried importing. I have tried opening the folder in explorer and putting the class in the same project. But, nothing seems to work.

Code:

```
public class WaterDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button continueWaterDetailsPart2;
    EditText duration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_water_details);


        duration = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enter_duration);

        duration.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String user = duration.getText().toString();
                if(duration.equals(" "))// if user inputs information
                //Then get calculations from other java file.

            }
        });
```

Sample Code:

**Second Java fie. The file I need to access.**

```
package ScubanauiTables;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class DurationCalculations {
    private int duration;

//Constructor

DurationCalculations(int duration, int maxDepth, int avgDepth, int temp, int visibility, int pressureStart,
                int pressureEnd, String[] diveConditions, String[] diveActivities) {
        setDuration(duration);
        setMaxDepth(maxDepth);
        setAvgDepth(avgDepth);
        setTemp(temp);
        setVisibility(visibility);
        setPressureStart(pressureStart);
        setPressureEnd(pressureEnd);
        setAirType(21);
        setDiveConditions(diveConditions);
        setDiveActivities(diveActivities);
        setPressureGroup();

    public int getDuration() {
        int temp = duration;
        return temp;
    }
    
    private void setDuration(int duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }
```

I hope this sample code makes sense. Thank you all for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use methods of your `DurationCalculation` class, and for that, you've to create an instance of that `class`.

You can instantiate and use your class like this

```
DurationCalculations durationCalculation = new DurationCalculations( 
         /*enter your constructor values*/);
```

Now you can call all public methods of your `DurationCalculations` class using `durationCalculation` variable like this

```
durationCalculation.getDuration();
```

You cannot call any `private` methods from outside of the class, like your `setDuration()` whose scope is set to `private`. For it be accessed outside of `DurationCalculations` class. You need to set it to `public`

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I will give this a shot and see what I can do. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Wait, when I create an instance of that class, do I do it in the DurationCalculations class or the WaterDetails class?

Comment: You've to create an `instance` of `DurationCalculations` in whatever class you want to use it. If you want to use it in the `WaterDetails` class, create an `instance` there.